# WordPress - How to map a URL path to a WP_Query?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress development and have created a custom type of `event`. I would now like to create a page which shows all upcoming events.

An `event` has the following fields:

- `title`
- `description`
- `event_date` (type is [CMB2's](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types) `text_date_timestamp`)

This works, and I have used `manage_edit-{$post_type}_columns` to create an admin UI that allows for sorting by `event_date`. So far so good. :-)

But now I want to map a URL like `www.example.com/upcoming-events` to a page which shows:

- Only show `event`s with an `event_date` in the future.
- Ordered by `event_date` in ascending order.

I need some help joining up a few dots ... I guess that I will need to use `WP_Query`. But how do I map the URL path to a page with this `WP_Query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create page with slug `upcoming-events` and place your custom shortcode (for instance, shortcode `[upcoming_events]`) inside page's content.

Then add the shortcode definition inside your functions.php:

```
add_shortcode('upcoming_events',function() {
    /* Use WP_Query and output the content you'd like to be displayed */
});
```